# Djinni swift project link error

Tags: ios, swift, djinni

```
[Your First Cross-Platform Djinni App: Part 2, iOS][1]
```

I follow this guidline and everything works well if I create the new project with Object-C project. However, I want to use Swift project, so I changed the project language and create a bridge to connect Swift with Object-C. But it can't work.

if I try to call this function, error happens

```
  let hw = LipHelloWorld.create()

 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__get_deleter(std::type_info const&) const", referenced from:
  vtable for std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<personalapp::HelloWorldImpl, std::__1::allocator<personalapp::HelloWorldImpl> > in libpersonalapp_objc.a(HelloWorldImpl.o)
  "std::__1::__next_prime(unsigned long)", referenced from:
```

Please help me!

hello_world.hpp

```
// AUTOGENERATED FILE - DO NOT MODIFY!
// This file generated by Djinni from personalapp.djinni

#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <string>
namespace personalapp {

class HelloWorld {
public:
    virtual ~HelloWorld() {}
    static std::shared_ptr<HelloWorld> create();
    virtual std::string get_hello_world() = 0;
};
}  // namespace personalapp
```

HelloWorldImpl.hpp

```
 #pragma once 
 #include "hello_world.hpp"

namespace personalapp {

class HelloWorldImpl : public personalapp::HelloWorld{
public:
    HelloWorldImpl();

    std::string get_hello_world() override;
};
}
```

PersonalApp-Bridging-Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include "LipHelloWorld.h"
```

Comment: Could you provide:
- your implementation of std::shared_ptr<HelloWorld> HelloWorld::create();
- Objective-C Bridging Header content?

Comment: @mkk I have updated the question detail and answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found the answer, click my project -> Build Settings --> All --> Linking --> Other Linker Flags, set its value to `-lc++`

Comment: That makes sense, since the missing symbol is from the STL.  I think you should be able to equivalently add libc++ to the "Link with Binary Libraries" build step, which might be a less hidden place to apply this setting.